# Calculating angles less than 0 using numpy.arccos?

Tags: python, angle

I am trying to calculate the a dihedral angle between four atoms. The measured angle is -53.5 degrees while the python code gave 53.5. I understand that arccos automatically rotates the angle to be in [0,180] range while I need the angles to be in [-180,180] range. How can this be achieved? Any help is appreciated.

```
    costheta    =   dotProduct(normal1, normal2)
    costheta    =   costheta/vectorLength(normal1)
    costheta    =   costheta/vectorLength(normal2)
    radians     =   arccos(costheta)
    theta       =   (180/pi)*radians
```

This is the section of the code that does the angle calculation. I can provide the template files and the full code separately.

Answer (score 0):

With just the cosinus, you will always have two possibilities for the angle. To let the angle determined, you can also calculate the sinus. For example, if the cosinus is greater than zero but the sinus is less than zero, you are sure your angle is negative. You can use the cross product to get the sinus.